# Question in proof of Schwarz lemma ( holomorphicity of function g)

Tags: complex-analysis

While studying Schwarz lemma proof from Wikipedia I got struck on a question. Actually it was not covered in my class and I came to know it's useful.

Link of proof :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

> Question : 1.my question is how did author proved that g must be holomorohic at z=0 ?

> 2. How does  in line of theorem statement starting with "Moreover" |f'(0) | = 1 implies f(z)= az with a$\in \mathbb{C} $ with |a|=1.( The page doesn't gives a proof of this and I don't get which result is being used).

I don't find a reason to deduce this.

Can you please tell?

Comment: $f$ is the sum of its power series on the entire disk, thus so is $g$ by construction. To conclude, note that a power series is holomorphic.

Comment: If $h$ is holomorphic on $B(c,r)\setminus \{c\}$ and if $\lim_{z \to c} h(z)=l$ exists then $c$ becomes a removable singularity and we can extend $h$ to a holomorphic function by defining its value at $c$ to be $l$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks got it!! Also, I had another question( in same proof) which I added to the post . Can you please answer it also?

Comment: Apply MMP to $g$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy unfortunately, still I am not able to deduce it. Can you please give a detailed answer?